# How to Import Data From an Excel File Using File Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel files one is Crash Diagram Program and other is Raw data. The name of second workbook is changed day by day, as it is generated by the system. I have used a VBA code for copying the specific range date from one workbook to another and its working fine.

The macro:

```
Sub ImportDatafromotherworksheet()
    Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select All Data You Want to Copy.", Title:="Select All Data", Default:="A1", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A2", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

How to copy the entire sheet from one workbook to another workbook without selecting the range? I tried to change the range with the sheet but it gives me error type mismatch.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your attempt at changing the range, and note what line specifically throws the type mismatch.

Comment: @BigBen I have edited the code. Please review it. I want to change the source range from selection range to the entire sheet and same for the destination sheet. I hope you get my point.